# VueJs not removing image after second button is clicked

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vue-component

So I'm trying to make a team comparison on my web app to compare their stats, the problem is that after I selected two teams then remove either one of the team, at first I succeed but when I try to remove the last one its doing nothing the last team logo is still showing up. Below is my code.

On the console it shows that **selectedTeams** values are undefined after **remove-first** and **remove-second** are clicked

```
undefined (2) [undefined, "TeamB", __ob__: Observer] 0
undefined (2) [undefined, undefined, __ob__: Observer] 1
```

**Display Team Logo**

```
<div class="col-md-6 first-selected">
    <img id="firstteamlogo" :src="selectedTeams[0] | spacetodash | useLGLogo" v-if="selectedTeams[0] || selectedTeams[0] != undefined">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 second-selected">
    <img id="secondteamlogo" :src="selectedTeams[1] | spacetodash | useLGLogo" v-if="selectedTeams[1] || selectedTeams[1] != undefined">
</div>
```

**Remove Team Logo**

```
<div class="add-area">
    <i class="fa fa-times remove-first" aria-hidden="true" v-if="selectedTeams[0]" v-on:click="removeTeams"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-plus select-first" aria-hidden="true" v-else></i>
    <span v-if="selectedTeams[0]">vs</span>
    <span v-else>Comparison</span>
    <i class="fa fa-times remove-second" aria-hidden="true" v-if="selectedTeams[1]" v-on:click="removeTeams"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-plus select-second" aria-hidden="true" v-else></i>
</div>
```

**Team Selection**

```
<div class="team-selection" v-if="showTeamSelection">
    <div class="team-row">
        <div class="col-md-3" v-for="(team, index) in teams" v-if="index < 4">
            <div class="team-logo">
                <img class="team" :src="team.clubName | spacetodash | useMDLogo" :id="team.clubName | removespace" :data-team-name="team.clubName" :data-team-id="team.teamId" v-on:click="selectTeams">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="team-row">
        <div class="col-md-3" v-for="(team, index) in teams" v-if="index > 3">
            <div class="team-logo">
                <img class="team" :src="team.clubName | spacetodash | useMDLogo" :id="team.clubName | removespace" :data-team-name="team.clubName" :data-team-id="team.teamId" v-on:click="selectTeams">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**VueJs Code**

```
export default {
    data: function(){
        return {
            teams: {},
            isTeamsSelected: true,
            isPlayersSelected: false,
            showTeamSelection: true,
            selectedTeams: [],
            selectedPlayers: [],
        }
    },
    mixins: [
        filters,
        methods
    ],
    methods: {
        selectTeams(e) {  
            if(this.selectedTeams.length < 2){
                this.selectedTeams.push(e.target.dataset.teamName);

                if(this.selectedTeams.length == 2){
                    this.showTeamSelection = false;
                }

                console.log(this.selectedTeams);
            } 
            return false;
        },
        removeTeams(e) {
            let removeTeam = e.target.classList.value;

            this.showTeamSelection = true;

            if(removeTeam.indexOf('remove-first') >= 0){
                this.selectedTeams[0] = undefined;
                console.log(this.selectedTeams[0], this.selectedTeams, 0);
            }
            if(removeTeam.indexOf('remove-second') >= 0){
                this.selectedTeams[1] = undefined;
                console.log(this.selectedTeams[1], this.selectedTeams, 1);
            }
        },
    },
    mounted: function() {
        let self = this;

        this.getCurrentSeasonTeams().then(function(response){
            if( response.status == 200 && response.data.length > 0 ) {
                self.teams = response.data;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Setting a value to undefined in an array is an unusual way to remove it. Why not just splice? I expect this is probably the root of your issue.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats

Comment: @BertEvans I tried to use this.selectedTeams[0] = '', this.selectedTeams[1] = '' and change my condition on the images but still no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the team you want to remove.

```
<i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" v-if="selectedTeams[0]" v-on:click="removeTeams(selectedTeams[0])"></i>
```

And change your removeTeam method.

```
removeTeams(team) {
  this.selectedTeams.splice(this.selectedTeams.indexOf(team), 1)
  this.showTeamSelection = true;
}
```